# BACK key does not finish activity

Tags: java, android

I am running a service that starts a new activity when specific
applications are launched.

For example, when I launch sms application, my service detects it by
checking a top activity package name and starts a new activity.

But the problem is that after starting a new activity, when I finish
that activity and press BACK button from sms application to go back to
Home screen, it does not finish my sms application.

Even though the screen is at home(launcher), when I check top activity
name, sms app is running as the top activity, which means sms app is
not finished after pressing BACK button.

I use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK intent flag for starting a new
activity and finish() to finish it. Does anyone have an idea why my
BACK button does not finish sms application in this case?

thanks,

777

Comment: Sounds like you're doing things really wrong. You have NO control over what happens after launching another activity. You can't rely on any specific behaviour.

Comment: I am not trying to control over sms application. I am just not getting why this sms app becomes top activity even if I am at my HOME screen.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, the back button will halt the current activity, whatever it's doing. If you absolutely need to finish it off, take a look at the [lifecycle of an activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife), and perhaps put some code into the onPause() and onStop() functions.

Comment: When I press back button, the task for sms App always gets terminated. However, it remains as the top activity when I starts a new activity from service after launching sms app. so I think starting a new activity from service is causing some problem in this case on my activity lifecycle. and I cannot put some code into the onPause() and onStop() functions of SMS app.

Answer (score 1):

OK if it doesnt workout.. try overriding the OnBackPressed method
and put finish() in that.. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to finish the activity when user navigate to back through device So you can use this code it is more helpful.

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that in my activity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        alert.setTitle("Wylogowanie i wylaczenie.");
        alert
            .setMessage("Exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    //DO SOMETHING YOU NEED eg. destroy/close DB, stop services, and move the task to back
                    db.getWritableDatabase(); //getDB
                    db.destroyDB(context); //Destroy it
                    db.close(); //and close
                    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SVCKeepLogged.class)); //stop some service
                    moveTaskToBack(true); //hide activity (this do not kill it - you can use finish() here)
                    //finish();
                }               
            })
            .setNegativeButton("NOOO!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //Keep app alive.
                    dialog.cancel();
                }

            });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    // TODO
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
        finish();
    }
}
```